# How to access each button's properties after they are dynamically generated in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have dynamically generated some number of buttons. Now i need to manipulate them in such a way that clicking on one button should do something on another button. How to do it? I would prefer the code to be as simple as possible as i am tutoring amateurs.

```
    Private Sub NewButton(ByVal ButtonNumber As Integer)
    ' set the button properties 

    btn.Name = "Button" & ButtonNumber
    btn.Enabled = True
    btn.Size = New Size(25, 25)
    btn.Visible = True
    'use tag to store number of button
    btn.Tag = ButtonNumber
    ' Add button click handler
    AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btnclick
    ' Add to this forms controls collection
    Me.Controls.Add(btn)
    arr1(count) = btn.Name
    count = count + 1
End Sub          


Private Sub NewButton(ByVal ButtonNumber As Integer)
    ' set the button properties 

    btn.Name = "Button" & ButtonNumber
    btn.Enabled = True
    btn.Size = New Size(25, 25)
    btn.Visible = True
    'use tag to store number of button
    btn.Tag = ButtonNumber
    ' Add button click handler
    AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btnclick
    ' Add to this forms controls collection
    Me.Controls.Add(btn)
    arr1(count) = btn.Name
    count = count + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Winforms? Webforms? WP7? Silverlight? WPF? Something else?

Comment: It would be helpful to include any relevant code you already have.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question to add detail to it instead of adding comments.

Answer (score 0):

associating an event to a dynamically create button:

```
AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf clickevent 'clickeven sub to handle the event

sub clickevent()
    For Each cn As Control In Me.Controls
      Select Case cn.GetType.ToString.Substring(cn.GetType. _
                                      ToString.LastIndexOf(".") +1).ToLower
            Case "button"
                'code goes here
        End Select
    Next
end sub
```

hope if fit you best, regards.

Comment: where should i add this? is it inside the new button function? Let me add on to what i said. I need all the 16 buttons thus generated to be identified individually. Clicking on one button should be able to perform something on other buttons.